# select rows where the values of 2 columns are swapped

Tags: r, select, duplicates, rows

I have a dataset with a list names and I am trying to find any entries that are duplicates but have the First Name and Last Name swapped. Something like this:

```
df:
 ID  Last Name   First Name  
 1   Doe         Jane
 2   Smith       John
 3   Woods       Natalie
 4   Jane        Doe
```

I want:

```
df:
 ID  Last Name  First Name
 1   Doe        Jane
 4   Jane       Doe
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Grp = paste(pmax(Last_Name, First_Name), pmin(Last_Name, First_Name))) %>%
 filter(n() > 1)

     ID Last_Name First_Name Grp     
  <int> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   
1     1 Doe       Jane       Jane Doe
2     4 Jane      Doe        Jane Doe
```